# How do I print pi (3.14159)?

Tags: command, math

What command could print pi for me? I want to specify how many digits it prints, I couldn't find anything online. I just want to be able to print pi.

Comment: Take your pick of languages: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Pi

Comment: Note that it gets more fun if you want more digits than around 15.

Comment: What do you mean Thorbjørn?

Comment: @DisplayName: it means that you can no longer use any program that internally stores/calculates PI using double precision floating point values (which is usually the highest precision "built-in" FP data type available in most languages).

Comment: My solution, decades ago before this was commonly provided by language libraries, was to memorize it to more places than the floating points I was using would ever need: 3.1415926535897932384626 is usually close enough for practical purposes, and even most impractical ones -- anything real-world is going to have more error than that in the other numbers, and for theoreticals I'd stick with the symbolic rather than numeric value.

Comment: @keshlam : See [How many digits of Pi do you know?](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=4742). FWIW, I memorised the first 100 places of pi several decades ago. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring: A friend of mine knew the square root of two to several thousand places... but as I said, that's a party trick, neither useful for calculation nor for theoretical work.

Comment: @keshlam: I'm glad your friend chose sqrt(2). Pi gets all the publicity, but historically speaking, the humble root 2 is where the whole irrational thing started. :) FWIW, I like to use approximations of sqrt(2) for mental arithmetic (derived from the continued fraction). Sure, memorising ridiculous amounts of digits of these numbers has no practical application, but it's great for your math-nerd street-cred. :)

Comment: I should mention a cute π approximation I discovered a couple of years ago: (22/7)*(1-0.0004) = 3.1416, exactly. IOW, you can improve the accuracy of a calculation that uses (22/7) for pi by reducing the result by 0.04%.

Comment: If you need help memorizing a random string of digits or something similar, setting it to music can help. The start of Pi can easily be sung to the Mexican Hat Dance, for example... <grin/>

Comment: Haha, thanks keshlam. In this case i don't need to remember anything.

Comment: Maybe this could be closed? Theres way too many answers already.

Comment: @DisplayName closing is only done for questions which don't belong here (either off-topic or simply a bad question), not for questions which have too many answers.

Comment: Okay, i have seen questions that are locked because too many people respond. But maybe thats only locked for people below 10 reputation.

Comment: @DisplayName because 15 digits are what native binary representations usually allow.  If you need more digits than that your program must switch to another representation without FPU-support which usually is slower.

Comment: @DisplayName In my book, I think it is a bit unfair to have this closed because so many people have favorited this question, so there *is* a lot of interest. Unfortunately a small oligarchy of 24/7 SE geeks always feel that they have to impose their opinion on the enormously huge rest by these hasty closings. Yes: it's always THE SAME names I read there. Over 5,000 views by now - but 0.1 percent of people dictate a closing. Reminds me of Mozilla developers who always think that what they remove from their software is what their users want to have removed as well.

Comment: @syntaxerror interest is irrelevant. If you were to post a question asking for naked pictures of celebrities, it would get thousands of views and quite possibly upvotes. That does not make it on topic. This question is a _classic_ example of too broad. Just look at the number of answers. Also note that the OP did not specify _any_ limitations which makes the possible answers essentially infinite. In any case, closing is not deleting. The question and all of its 23 answers will still be here. Closing just means that no more answers are accepted. Do we really need even more ways to print π?

Comment: @terdon do you really think a celebrity like e.g. [Craig Charles](http://www.mirror.co.uk/tv/tv-news/im-celebrity-2014-line-up-craig-4608745) would draw that many views?

Comment: Do the digits need to be from the decimal expansion of pi, or would some other number bases be ok?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
echo "scale=5; 4*a(1)" | bc -l
3.14159
```

Where scale is the number of digits after decimal point.

Reference: http://www.tux-planet.fr/calculer-le-chiffre-pi-en-ligne-de-commande-sous-linux/

Comment: Shorter version in `bash` and other shells supporting here strings: `bc -l <<< "scale=5; 4*a(1)"`.

Comment: I wonder how many digits this can go?

Comment: @DisplayName quite a few. `scale=1000` gives 999 correct digits rather quickly (the last digit is off by 1, reasonable since we're computing pi/4 and then multiplying by 4). `scale=4000` gives 4000 correct digits in a few seconds. `scale=10000` takes longer than I have patience for, but probably gives 9999 or 10000 correct digits.

Comment: This gives an incorrect result on my machine, typing 'echo "scale=5; 4*a(1)" | bc -l' returns 3.14156, when the last digit should by 9

Comment: @JordanBentley, I have added an [answer with correct rounding of the result](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166582/19702).

Comment: @hobbs `scale=10000` took 7m26s on my machine. Didn't check valid digits though :)

Answer (score 63):

If you have `tex(1)` installed:

```
tex --version | head -1 | cut -f2 -d' '
```

Comment: This is almost worth an upvote just for being clever. Though the output of this changes when you upgrade the package. Shall we consider that to be a feature or a bug?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Actually, it changes to be a more precise approximation of pi.

Comment: @Abrixas2 Yes, I know. With the last version of TeX being version π.

Comment: The question asks for control over the number of digits, which this method does not give.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Fewer digits can be printed via an additional invocation of `cut`.  More digits can be printed by waiting a long time and running the command again.

Comment: @DavidRicherby you just have to wait long enough.  When Donald Knuth dies the version number of TeX will by definition be \Pi.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen but this won't print infinite number of digits I guess...

Comment: @Ruslan depends on the implementation.  I would expect in this particular case that it would be done "right".

Comment: + pi/pi for you

Comment: (Un)important note: GNOME is at π too at the moment. (v3.14) But Raspberry Pi was obviously quicker ;-)

Answer (score 24):

For printing with arbitrary precision, you could use `bc` and the formula `pi = 4*atan(1)`:

```
# bc -l
scale=<your precision>
4*a(1)
```

Comment: There's something _funny_ about the `scale` option, `pi = 3.141592..` but with `echo "scale=5; 4*a(1)" | bc -l =>
3.14156` I would then expect to see `3.14159` ?

Comment: `scale` specifies the precision to use for calculation, so with `scale=5`, no operation will use more than five fractional digits for any atomic operation.

Comment: @fduff, I have added an [answer with correct rounding of the result](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166582/19702).

Answer (score 20):

If you want something that can **compute the value of π,** then there are several approaches. Perhaps the most obvious solution would be to use a ready-made package like [`pi` (Debian package link)](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/pi), which if Debian's package description is to be trusted can compute the value to an arbitrary precision, limited only by memory.

`pi` is actually an example that's included with the [CLN library (Class Library for Numbers)](http://www.ginac.de/CLN/). It includes example applications that provide tools for generating arbitrary lengths of numbers such as Pi, Fibonacci, etc. CLN packages are available pre-packaged in Debian/Ubuntu (that's what the Debian link above is pointing to).

*Examples*

```
$ ./pi 10
3.141592653

$ ./pi 20
3.1415926535897932384
```

**NOTE:** The source of these examples is [here in the source for the CLN code base](http://www.ginac.de/CLN/cln.git/?p=cln.git;a=tree;f=examples;h=b618779205cbe74e03225d607c35c489de2cb493;hb=HEAD).

#### Other distros

*Fedora*

On Fedora I had to download the source tarball and build it myself, but it builds with little fuss. For whatever reason the package `cln` on Fedora includes just the library but neglects the examples that are available in the Debian/Ubuntu version (above).

*Arch*

Arch provides the same program in [the `cln` package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/cln/) (thanks [Amphiteót](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/44370/amphite%c3%b3t)).

Comment: Yeah, heh I meant the total value i just typed what i had in my head.

Comment: The "total value"?? Meaning what...?

Comment: @DisplayName read the rest of the answer. A dedicated program like `pi` sounds like exactly what you're looking for. You can do things like `pi 300` to print the first 300 digits for example.

Comment: @KyleStrand I have discovered a truly marvellous answer to that, which this comment is too narrow to contain. Hey, [it worked for Fermat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem#Fermat.27s_conjecture)!

Comment: I would love to know why this has received two downvotes. Did the people who downvoted not read the answer before they decided it was not useful?

Answer (score 19):

For up to a million digits you can use the following (here for 3000 digits):

```
curl --silent http://www.angio.net/pi/digits/pi1000000.txt | cut -c1-3000
```

Comment: This has the additional benefit that it should be reasonably close to O(1) complexity. Or maybe that isn't a benefit after all...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling If the OP wants some heavy calculation to test the effectiveness of the CPU fan, that might indeed not be what (s)he wants.

Comment: Also, it's difficult to say that any network interaction is O(1) time complexity in a practical world. :P

Comment: @HalosGhost For our purposes (compared to computing *n* digits of pi each time), downloading a fixed amount of data from a specific server over a network is likely to be *effectively* O(1), whereas computing *n* digits of pi is likely to be *at least* something like O(log n) and quite possibly higher (I'm not familiar with those algorithms). The actual download of the data is likely to take significantly more time than the overhead to start the download, hence the download time dominates and you get somewhere in the vicinity of O(1) given a reasonably fixed data transmission rate. Hence O(1).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling When you say O(1) don't you actually mean O(n)? The download time in linear in the number of digits you need, hence O(n).

Comment: @CodesInChaos No, the download time is constant (given constant transmission rate) because you are downloading a constant number of digits (one million, here). Unless (in this specific case) curl is smart enough to print while downloading and stop downloading once the pipe breaks because `cut` exits? If that is the case, I agree, it would be O(n).

Comment: Download time can be taken out of the equation by downloading the txt file once: π is not going to change any time soon, is it?

Comment: A couple of seconds in python give a million digits `from mpmath import mp; mp.dps = 1000000 ; print(mp.pi)`.

Comment: @Isaac That doesn't work on Python 3.7: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpmath'`. And it is in general nonsensical if you need to download and install something to be able to run a python program where you can download the result you want directly.

Comment: @Anthon You need to install the library: `pip3 install mpmath`.

Answer (score 15):

Some of the other answers show incorrect digits at the last places of the output. Below is a variation of [the answer using `bc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166223/19702) but with a better rounded result. The variable `s` contains the number of significant digits (including `3` in front of the decimal point).

### Round half up

```
$ bc -l <<< "s=5; scale=s+2; pi=4*a(1)+5*10^(-s); scale=s-1; pi/1"
3.1416
```

### Round down (truncate)

```
$ bc -l <<< "s=5; scale=s+2; pi=4*a(1); scale=s-1; pi/1"
3.1415
```

### Explanation of the rounding

The rounding is performed directly in `bc`. This does not have the limitation of the command `printf` which uses the C language [`double` type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) representation for the numbers which has a precision of about 17 significant digits. See the [answer with `printf` rounding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166385/19702).

`scale=s-1` sets the number of digits to truncate to. `pi/1` divides the result by 1 to apply the truncation. Simple `pi` does not truncate the number.

Rounding half up requires to add 5 to the first digit which will be cut off (5×10<sup>-s</sup>) so that in case of digits higher of equal 5 the last digit which will remain will be incremented.

From the [tests by hobbs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166220/how-do-i-print-pi-3-14159#comment273621_166223) it seems that three additional digits which will be rounded / cut off (`scale=s+2`) will suffice even for very long numbers.

### Here strings

The examples above use [here strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings) which are supported for example in `bash`, `ksh` and `zsh`. If your shell does not support here string use `echo` and pipe instead:

```
$ echo "s=5; scale=s+2; pi=4*a(1); scale=s-1; pi/1" |  bc -l
3.1415
```

Comment: Computing three additional digits for the purpose of rounding is not “correct rounding” as you claim in a comment. First, you don't have a bound on the error of the computation. If it can be wrong by 3 units in the last place as claimed by fduff, why wouldn't it be wrong by 1000 units in the last place? Second, see “the table maker's dilemma”.

Answer (score 12):

perl one line (using [bignum](http://search.cpan.org/~tels/bignum-0.23/lib/bignum.pm)):

```
perl -Mbignum=bpi -wle 'print bpi(NUM)'
```

e.g

```
perl -Mbignum=bpi -wle 'print bpi(6)'
3.14159
```

Comment: For 10.000 digits: Close to 8 minutes in perl, less than 4 in bc. Not the fastest.

Answer (score 9):

With python2:

```
$ python -c "import math; print(str(math.pi)[:7])"
3.14159
```

Comment: For completeness's sake, this solution is python2-specific.

Comment: After the edit, with the `(..)` this works in Python 2 and 3. Only seems to have 12 digits.

Comment: $ python -c "import math; print(format(math.pi, '.400f'))"
3.1415926535897931159979634685441851615905761718750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: @ArtemShitov - my bad, try importing _gmpy2_ (if you have it installed): `python -c "import gmpy2; print(str(gmpy2.const_pi(8192))[:400])"`. Increase precision for more digits... e.g. `python -c "import gmpy2; print(str(gmpy2.const_pi(16384))[:4400])"`

Comment: The fastest I could find was `from mpmath import mp; mp.dps = 1000000 ; print(mp.pi)` just a couple of seconds for a million digits. Not bad at all !!!.

Answer (score 7):

Using Ruby:

```
require "bigdecimal"
require "bigdecimal/math"
include BigMath

BigDecimal(PI(100)).round(9).to_s("F")

3.141592654
```

Comment: One liner: `ruby -e 'require "bigdecimal"; require "bigdecimal/math"; include BigMath; puts BigDecimal(PI(100)).round(9).to_s("F")'`

Answer (score 4):

In bash:

```
$ read -a a <<< $(grep M_PIl /usr/include/math.h) ; echo ${a[3]} | tr -d L
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884
```

Comment: @Amphiteóth `afmtodit` requires `groff` to be installed. Here on Ubuntu (& flavors), it is *not* standard. JFYI.

Comment: @syntaxerror Thank you, good point! I have removed my example. My point was just when read this A I ran `grep` on my system searching for the constant and found it in more than one places. That's why this was +1 for me!

Answer (score 3):

Very simple in PHP using the built in pi() function:

```
<?php 
echo round(pi(), 2);
?>
```

Comment: Can you [edit] this to give a command line version?

Answer (score 3):

How did I miss this question...

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26478803/4014959)'s a little Python pi program of mine that I posted a couple of weeks ago on Stack Overflow. It's not particularly fast, but it can do *lots* of digits. :) However, as I mentioned in that thread, I generally use Python's mpmath module for arbitrary precision arithmetic, and mpmath has a rather fast pi maker.

Eg,

```
time python -c "from mpmath import mp;mp.dps=500000;print mp.pi" >bigpi

real    0m4.709s
user    0m4.556s
sys     0m0.084s
```

500000 decimals of pi in under 5 seconds isn't too shabby, IMHO, considering it's running on a machine with a single core 2GHz processor, 2 gig of RAM, and writing to an elderly IDE drive.

Comment: Try `from mpmath import mp; mp.dps = 1000000 ; print(mp.pi)` (after a pip3 install mpmath) under two seconds for a million digits. Not bad at all !!!.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `node.js` installed, this will do its best at finding pi for you, though its best isn't very good:

```
node -e 'for(a=0,b=4E8,m=Math,r=m.random;b--;)a+=(1>m.sqrt((c=r())*c+(d=r())*d));console.log(a/1E8)'
```

Sample outputs:

```
3.14157749
3.1416426
3.14159055
3.14171554
3.14176165
3.14157587
3.14161137
3.14167685
3.14172371
```

Comment: The shorter `node -e 'console.log(Math.PI)'` is a little better than its best.

Comment: @chbrown That doesn't satisfy the OPs "not serious" requirement.

Comment: What "not serious" requirement? The OP just stated that they're asking for fun not that they want answers that are somehow "not serious". What does that mean anyway? Something like `echo pie`?

Comment: I typed that because when you ask questions sometimes people say that "this is not a script writing factory", so i said that because theres no real reason for it, i just want to know how to print pi.

Comment: @Amphiteóth It takes about 20 seconds to run on my computer. You might just need to give it some time.

Comment: @Amphiteóth You can also shorten how long it runs for like this: `node -e 'for(a=0,b=1E7,m=Math,r=m.random;b--;)a+=(1>m.sqrt((c=r())*c+(d=r())*d));console.log(a/.25E7)'`. That will run quickly, but give slightly less accurate results, like `3.14232, 3.140954, 3.1414976, ...`

Comment: I just edited the `4E8` to `1E7` and the `1E8` to `.25E7` to decrease the running time to 1/40th of it's original time.

Comment: Thank you, it seems I was impatient with the original command, takes longer on my rig but works! The command you put in the comment above gives me _SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL_ with an arrow underneath the "l" of log. Thanks +1

Answer (score 2):

**Monte Carlo Method**

See, for example, [this](http://www.eveandersson.com/pi/monte-carlo-circle) for an explanation of this method.

*Caveats*

- Not arbitrarily accurate
- Takes a long time to converge to anything useful

*Advantages*

Fun :-)

```
perl -Mbignum -E '
    for(0 .. 1_000_000){
        srand;
        $x=rand; # Random x coordinate
        $y=rand; # Random Y coordinate
        $decision = $x**2 + $y**2 <=1 ? 1:0; # Is this point inside the unit circle?
        $circle += $decision;
        $not_circle += 1-$decision;
        $pi = 4*($circle/($circle+$not_circle)); 
        say $pi
     }'
```

Note: I first tried it without `srand` but it got stuck at `3.14` and the digits after that kept oscillating, never converging. This is probably because, after a while the PRNG starts repeating itself. The use of `srand` will avoid that or at least lengthen the period of the pseudo-random sequence. This is all conjecture, so feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Amphiteót Not really sure what is going on there. If it helps my Perl is v5.14.2. I'm not really well-versed with `bignum` operations in Perl, I'm afraid and I don't know of any particular parts of the above program that require a newer Perl. Anyway, what's interesting about this is the algorithm itself. Try implementing it in your language of choice if this Perl isn't working for you.

Comment: @Amphiteót I see. Does the edit solve your problem?

Comment: @Amphiteót You can try adding `($x,$y,$circle,$not_circle)=(0,0,0);` before the loop to make sure all variables are defined before being used.

Comment: @Amphiteót My mistake. The parens above should have been `(0,0,0,0)`.

Comment: Re [this](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=119863)/5.20.1: Makes sense but didn't see it! Indeed `($x,$y,$circle,$not_circle)=(0,0,0,0)`. After a minute or two it was hanging around the desired value then it went much closer to 3.1409 before I stopped. Interesting and fun! Thank you!

Comment: This is the same algorithm as I did in JavaScript below

Comment: @Paulpro Sorry I missed that. My JavaScript knowledge is null.

Answer (score 2):

**PHP**

Few examples:

```
php -r "print pi();"
php -r 'echo M_PI;'
echo "<?=pi();" | php
```

If you want to change the precision try:

```
php -d precision=100 -r 'echo pi();'
```

> The size of a float is platform-dependent, although a maximum of
>   ~1.8e308 with a precision of roughly 14 decimal digits is a common
>   value (the 64 bit IEEE format). [[read more]](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

---

If you looking for even more accurate precision, check [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Pi) or [Code Golf SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi) for some programming solutions.

Related: [Software that can calculate PI to at least a thousand digits](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/782/3474) at SR.SE

Answer (score 2):

You can use a spigot algorithm for pi. The following C program by Dik Winter and Achim Flammenkamp will produce the first 15,000 digits of pi, one digit at a time.

```
a[52514],b,c=52514,d,e,f=1e4,g,h;main(){for(;b=c-=14;h=printf("%04d",e+d/f))for(e=d%=f;g=--b*2;d/=g)d=d*b+f*(h?a[b]:f/5),a[b]=d%--g;}
```

Comment: Context: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spigot_algorithm), [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~alopez-o/math-faq/mathtext/node12.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084571).

Comment: I love the spigot algorithm for logarithmic constants by Borwein, Bailey and Plouffe, however, this isn't code golf, so may I improve the readability of your code by reformatting it? Also note that BPP-style algorithms can only output digits for pi in bases that are powers of 2, at least without using additional memory.

Comment: @Franki does formatting the code change the meaning or intention of the post? If not, it should be fine (and the edit can always be rolled back). I don't see how deobfuscating some code could do something else than clarifying.

Comment: I wish someone could explain how that strange number of 52514 can be explained (ideally a formula). This algorithm is quoted in an uncountable number of pages in the net, but nobody has ever explained why of all numbers it's 52514. And it's no 5-minute job to understand, let alone "break apart" the formulae behind this algorithm.

Comment: @syntaxerror It is to produce exactly 15,000 digits before stopping. The output in the second for-loop produces 4 digits of pi and decrements the mystery number of 52514 by 14. The equation would then be 4*(52514/14) which equals 15004. The last 14 values in the array are ignored to take advantage of fewer tokens to get our exact value of 15000.

Comment: Thanks! But still I'd like to know how they came up with this number the first place. I suspect a tricky formula.

Comment: @11684 No, it really wouldn't change the meaning or intention of the code. However, I realized this is not a BBP-style spigot algorithm for pi, but another one that someone else has already deobfuscated here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25837097

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script that prints pi with the number of digits specified (including '.') by the user.

**pi.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
len=${1:-7}
echo "4*a(1)" | bc -l | cut -c 1-"$len"
```

**output**

```
$ ./pi.sh 10
3.14159265
```

and with default value:

```
$ ./pi.sh
3.14159
```

I've seen people using `scale` as a `bc` option, but in my case (`bc 1.06.95`) this does not output the correct value:

```
$ echo "scale=5;4*a(1)" | bc -l
3.14156
```

Notice the last digit.

Comment: The question says, "I want to specify how many digits it prints," which, strictly speaking, is ambiguous -- but I think your answer fails (on a technicality) under any reasonable interpretation; your `./pi.sh 10` prints nine digits, counting the initial `3`. Also, you're pointing the finger of rounding error, but your `./pi.sh 6` outputs `3.1415`, which might not be optimal.

Comment: From memory, the `scale=X` option of `bc` will NOT round the number, but simply cut off the number at the X-th decimal digit.

Answer (score 1):

I like Abey's answer but did not like how bc was changing the last digit.

```
echo "scale=5; 4*a(1)" | bc -l
3.14156
```

So I removed scale used printf to set the number of digits.

```
printf "%0.5f\n" $(echo "4*a(1)" | bc -l)
3.14159
```

Comment: Have you noticed, after a scale of 62 digits, they're all 0 whereas this doesn't happen with the original command.

Comment: @Amphiteót, That is because `printf` has a severe limitation on the floating point numbers in comparison to `bc`. They are represented by C language [`double` type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)  with precision of about 17 digits so even **the non-zero digits after about the 17th one are bogus!** ------ I have added an [answer with correct rounding of the result not limited by `printf`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166582/19702). ------ Also to ensure that this command works with various locales you must do something like this: `LC_ALL=C printf`...

Answer (score 1):

*It can be assumed that the OP is interested in a short, easy to memorize shell command to print π - but the question does not really say that. This answer is ignoring that assumption and answers the question strictly as written;*

### Trivial?

While there are 18 answers already, one approach is still missing - and with so many answers, it one could think it't the only one that is missing:
The trivial one:
How to print π? Just print π!

That approach seems to be too useless to even think about it, but I will show that it does have it's merrits:

### Optimized

We'd normally calculate the value of π. I don't see what's keeping us from optimizing the solution, by precalculating the value - it's a constant, any compiler would do that.

We want some number of digits of π, up to a maximum precision. So we can just take the prefix of the constant, as text:

```
echo 3.1415926535897932384626433832795 | cut -b -7
3.14159
```

A variant with an explicit argument for the precision, eg. for precision `5`:

```
echo 3.1415926535897932384626433832795 | cut -b -$((2+5))
3.14159
```

### Advantages

The maximum precision can be choosen arbitrarily by using a suitable constant calculated using one of the other answers. It is limited only by the maximal length of a command line.
It has constant time complexity for finding the value.
It makes all limits and constraints obvious, based on the low complexity of implementation.
It handles precision larger than the maximum gracefully by returning the constant in the full available precision (with no trailing `0`).
So this solution, while trivial, does have advantages. It may be useful when it's used in a shell function, for example.

### Minimal

The functionality of the solution above can also be inplemented without creating a process for `cut` (assuming `echo` is a shell builtin). It uses the command `printf` (normally a builtin) in a somewhat obscure way:
The constant is completely handeled as a string (the format uses `%s`), there is no floating point arithmethic involved, so the limits of `float` or `double` do not apply here.
The precision value of the `%s` escape (`5` in the example below) specifies the length of the string prefix to print - which is the precision. The `3.` is part of the `printf` format to keep it out of the precision calculation.

```
$ printf "3.%.5s\n" 1415926535897932384626433832795 
3.14159
```

Alternative with precision as separate argument:

```
$ printf "3.%.*s\n" 5 1415926535897932384626433832795 
3.14159
```

Or slightly more readable (Note the space between `3.` and `14159...`, they are separate arguments):

```
$ printf "%s%.5s\n" 3. 1415926535897932384626433832795
3.14159
```

### Fast

The variant using `printf` can be expected to be very fast: Because `printf` is a shell builtin in common shells like `bash` and `zsh`, it does not create any processes.
Also, it does not touch any kind of floating point related code, but only manipulation of byte arrays (explicitly not multibyte characters). This is usually faster, often much faster than the use of floating point.

#### printf compatibility

Often, there are reasons to replace  `printf` by  `/usr/bin/printf` to guarantee consistency or compatibility. In this case, I think we can use the builtin - which is important, as using `/usr/bin/printf` reduces the "fast" advantage by forking a process.
A common problem with `printf` compatibility is the number output format depending on the locale. The separating `.` for numbers can be changed to `,` based on locale setting; But we do not use numbers, just a string constant containing a literal `.` - unaffected by locale.
StéphaneChazelas pointed out that `printf %.5s` works differently in `zsh`, by counting characters, not bytes as usual. Luckily, our constants use only characters in the lower ASCII-range, which is encoded by one byte per character in any relevant encoding, as long as we use the common `UTF-8` encoding for Unicode, and not a fixed width encoding.

Comment: Note that `printf %.5s` is char (not byte) based in zsh (sensibly, but against POSIX). `ksh93`'s `%.5Ls` is graphem based.

Answer (score 1):

What if you can't for the life of you remember this `arctan` thing? Or supposing you don't even know this function exists in `bc`, then try to memorize this simple division:

```
echo "scale=6; 355 / 113" | bc
3.141592
```

Will only work for 6 digits, but for non-scientific calculations this will do fine.

If you think you can't remember these two numbers either, write the denominator first, then the numerator:

113 355

Or why not

**11 33 55**

"double 1, double 3, double 5". All figures are odd. To calculate, split the 6-digit number in half again, and swap denominator and numerator before dividing them. That's about it.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, I find `4 * arctan(1)` a lot easier to remember that 2 three-digits numbers... I'd easily use 335 instead of 355, or 133 instead of 113.

Comment: Well, I think it's a matter of personal preference.:) People (like me) who can easily memorize (landline!) phone numbers would be able to memorize two numbers just as one single phone number. It will also help those people who at school felt that trigonometry must've been made by evil powers.